# Resizing of component view in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to resize between components two and three; which is not working. Whereas component one and div (which contains two and three components) is working.
Please find below code which i did so far.
Can someone please answer the mistake i am doing or correct way of doing.

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RendererLogger } from '@app/utils/logger/renderer-logger';

const logger = new RendererLogger('TestLayoutComponent');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-layout',
  templateUrl: './test-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-layout.component.less']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  positionY = 0;
  positionYPercent = 0;
  positionY1 = 0;
  maxHeight = 100;
  
/*
  constructor() { }
*/

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  mousemoveEvent: any = null;
  mouseupEvent: any = null;
  dragging: (event: any) => void;
  mouseup: (event: any) => void;

  mousemoveEvent1: any = null;
  mouseupEvent1: any = null;
  dragging1: (event: any) => void;
  mouseup1: (event: any) => void;
    
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.mouseup = this.unboundMouseup.bind(this);
    this.dragging = this.unboundDragging.bind(this);
    this.mouseup1 = this.unboundMouseup1.bind(this);
    this.dragging1 = this.unboundDragging1.bind(this);
  }

    unboundMouseup(event: any) {
        // Remove listeners
        this.mousemoveEvent(logger.info("this " + this));
        this.mouseupEvent(logger.info("this " + this));

    }

    mousedown(event: MouseEvent) {
      if (event.button === 0/*only left mouse click*/) {
          // if listeners exist, first Remove listeners
          if (this.mousemoveEvent) {
              this.mousemoveEvent();
          }
          else if (this.mouseupEvent) {
              this.mouseupEvent();
          }

          this.mousemoveEvent = this.renderer.listen("document", "mousemove", this.dragging);
          this.mouseupEvent = this.renderer.listen("document", "mouseup", this.mouseup);
      }
  }

  unboundDragging(event: any) {
    
    logger.info("unboundDragging event.pageX " + event.pageX + " event.pageY " + event.pageY + 
            " this.positionY " + this.positionY + " this.positionY1 " + this.positionY1 )
    this.positionY = event.pageY;
    this.positionYPercent = this.positionY/100;
  }

  /////////////////
  
  

    unboundMouseup1(event: any) {
        // Remove listeners
        this.mousemoveEvent1();
        this.mouseupEvent1();

    }

    mousedown1(event: MouseEvent) {
      if (event.button === 0/*only left mouse click*/) {
          // if listeners exist, first Remove listeners
          if (this.mousemoveEvent1) {
              this.mousemoveEvent1();
          }
          else if (this.mouseupEvent1) {
              this.mouseupEvent1();
          }

          this.mousemoveEvent1 = this.renderer.listen("document", "mousemove", this.dragging1);
          this.mouseupEvent1 = this.renderer.listen("document", "mouseup", this.mouseup1);
      }
  }

  unboundDragging1(event: any) {
    logger.info("unboundDragging1 event.pageX " + event.pageX + " event.pageY " + event.pageY +
            " this.positionY " + this.positionY + " this.positionY1 " + this.positionY1 )
    this.positionY1 = event.pageY;
  }

}
```

**less file**

```
:host {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; //border: 2px deeppink solid; // DEBUG
  height: ~'calc(100vh - 60px)'; // temporary fix, until top components layout not changed to flex
  background-color: white;
  // height: 100%;
  

  .cdt-one-container {
    height: calc(98% / 3);
    min-height: calc(30% / 3);
    //flex: 1;
    //display: flex; // overflow: hidden;
    //border: 1px #1fff00 solid; // DEBUG
    app-one {
      // overflow-x: hidden;
    }
  }

  .cdt-two-and-three-container {
    height: calc(196% / 3);
    min-height: calc(30% / 2);
    flex: 1;
    display: flex; // overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;

  .cdt-two-container {
    height: calc(98% / 3);
    flex: 1;
    display: flex; // overflow: hidden;
    //border: 1px #004bff solid; // DEBUG
  }

  .cdt-three-container {
    height: calc(98% / 3);
    //min-height: calc(30% / 3);
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
  }
}

  .dragbar1{
    //flex: none;
    display: flex;
    background-color:black;
    min-height: 2px;
    cursor: row-resize;
 }

 .dragbar2{
  //flex: none;
  display: flex;
  background-color:black;
  height: 1px;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

}
```

**html file**

```
<div class="cdt-one-container"
  [ngStyle]="{'height': (positionY) + 'px'}" >
  <app-one></app-one>
</div>

<div class="dragbar1" (mousedown)="mousedown($event)"></div>

<div class="cdt-two-and-three-container" [ngStyle]="{'height': (positionY + positionY1) + 'px'}">
  <div class="cdt-two-container" [ngStyle]="{'height': (positionY1) + 'px'}">
  <app-two></app-two>
</div>
<div class="dragbar2" (mousedown)="mousedown1($event)"></div>
  <div class="cdt-three-container" [ngStyle]="{'height': (positionY - positionY1) + 'px'}">
  <app-three></app-three>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use this package, https://angular-split.github.io/ it provides flexible split functionality

Comment: Thanks.. our angular version is 7, and i see angular split UI library is built for angular 11. Thanks for you answer, i will check the angular split UI library for my learning.